# navigation app with a different route finding algorithm

Tags: android, navigation, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I wish to make an android app that leverages [OSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android) services and runs an algorithm of my choice to find the route, say *A** or *some heuristic on Dijkstra*.

The [Routing](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing) wiki page of OSM has some good pointers but it does not give any insight about how to go about implementing your own algorithm in the app.

Comment: What is your motivation and scope? Do you want to try out / learn different algorithms for routing? Or do you won't to primarily learn how to build and android app? Or do you want to build a production ready solution to some problem? Based on your question you may not be aware of size and complexity of the topic you chose.

Comment: What is your actual question? How to write a routing algorithm? How to read raw OSM data?

Comment: @JosefAdamcik @scai 
I have an algorithm that outputs a `route` from _source_ to _destination_ depending on some constraints. I have calculated this `route` on actual map data after processing _<some-place>.osm_ files. Now, I wish to build a production-ready/usable app that leverages real-time OSM features/data (which I'm not sure how to use) and shows the `route` in app which is the output of my algorithm (instead of using Dijkstra).

My aim is to demonstrate the working of my algorithm, in the backend, on a navigation app.

Comment: In this case take a look at [osmdroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid) or the [Android](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android) page in the OSM wiki.

Answer (score 1):

This response is overview which might help you to orient better in the landscape and find a way to approach the problem. Your question is too broad to give an exact simple answer but I do understand why are you asking such question.

You can use [Osmdroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid) library to display the route you have on Android.

Keep in mind that the core feature of Osmdroid is to  display the map tiles. Map tiles are just bitmaps so you need either an online source of tiles or an offline one. How to do that is covered in the documentation and partly in other questions on SO. It's a too big topic to explain it here in detail. Just to make it clear: `.osm` file with raw OpenstreetMap data cannot be directly rendered by Osmdroid. Map tiles are usually rendered from that data in quite complex way and not on the fly.

Another very important feature in Osmdroid library is the ability to display so called Overlays. E.g. Markers, polygons etc. You may use those to draw your route on the map and other features you may wish to display. This is again covered in the documentation and too big to go in details here.

There is a support for routing for Osmdroid (AFAIK in Osmbonuspack) but that's about using some 3rd party service to get your routing data and displaying that. According to your comment you want to implement your own algorithm and therefore this would be no use to you.

So the last part is how to integrate your algorithm into that. That's not a simple question with a simple answer. You'll need to do almost everything on your own, starting with getting the data you need to run the algorithm from the OpenstreetMap database (`.osm` file). I don't think there's an API which would provide you reasonable way to access the data in a form suitable for route computation. The approach I would choose is to develop some kind of preprocessing which would take either `.osm` file or a database with the data an produce my own structure representing the graph for navigation. I would than include this graph in my application and run my algorithm on that data. The output of my algorithm would be the route: a list of coordinates which I would use to draw the polyline.

If the area you need to cover is small enough, you may start with including the `.osm` file in your project and running the algorithm in the same was as you do now. Maybe it's going to be good enough for your situation.

One interesting project to look at to find inspiration is [Graphopper](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper) - they have build exactly what I said above and they use it to provide a library for Android/iOs and a web API. But the core is the same - pre-process OSM data into graph data and run the algorithm on that. Since you wish to implement the algorithm on your own this library will not help you (unless you fork the project and modify it) but it might be a valuable learning resource.